# In htaccess, how to set a response header for all URLs of except one?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-headers

I want to use this rule:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set X-FRAME-OPTIONS "DENY"
</IfModule>
```

But only for the front pages of my website.

I.e. I have a backoffice : `example.com/gestion` for which I don't want the rule to apply and I want to have the rule applied only for `example.com` (so all URLs without `gestion`)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this using an Apache `<If>` expression to match all URLs, except for any URL that starts `/gestion` or contains multiple path segments or contains dots (ie. actual files).

For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/(?!gestion)[\w-]*$#">
    Header always set X-FRAME-OPTIONS "DENY"
</If>
```

This uses a negative lookahead to avoid matching any URL that starts `/gestion`.

I'm assuming that your "front page" URLs only consist of single path segments containing characters in the range `[0-9a-zA-Z_-]`.

The `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required (unless this is *optional* and you are using the same config on multiple server's where mod_headers may not be enabled - unlikely).